# Applescript assistive access on M1 Monterey. Normal fixes not working

Tags: permissions, applescript, system, macos-monterey

a couple scripts I've made in the past that open things up no longer work on M1 Monterey it seems. They DO work in the Script Editor, but once I try to turn it into an application so that I can stick it in the dock or trigger it from the calendar, it won't open. It keeps giving the error

'System Events got an error: openBookmarkFolder_subsets5 is not allowed assistive access. (-1719)'

I have read a bunch of other questions like this one, and I HAVE allowed the script, script editor, terminal, system events, and applescript utility in the accessibility tab of the privacy section of preferences. Its still not working.

Also that whole section seems broken because the permissions never seem to stick, I have it ticked to allow access to removable devices and it keeps asking me that every time still.

This script is on a removable SSD, and the things it opens are on the same drive. When I try to run it as a standalone, it asks to access the removable drive 4 times in a row, and then gives the assistive access error.

I would like a fix to this

ALSO it wouldn't allow me to open any files due to permissions until that file was already manually opened at least once. That was annoying but I already opened them all, just figured I'd mention that.

Comment: For an AppleScript application, it needs to be code signed (or the script made read-only) so that it doesn’t get modified, which would be why the permissions aren’t sticking.  For the files, check that they aren’t quarantined.

Comment: I tried that, it's not working :( 

I just tried exporting > application > set to run only, and the code sign box says 'sign to run locally'

The only other option is 'dont code sign'

Same exact thing happens....it asks to access the removable drive, I say yes 4 times and then the assistive access error appears

I dont believe the files are quarantined but how would i tell?